# Unity3d AudioClip played with AudioSource not working properly

Tags: c#, audio, mono, unity-game-engine

So I did (in Unity editor):

`GameObject -> Create Empty`

the I dragged my Avatar.cs (the main player animation `MonoBehaviour`) onto the gamefile.

Inside Avatar.cs I added:

`public AudioClip audioClipJump;`

and

```
// this is where the jump animation gets played
audio.PlayOneShot(audioClipJump);
```

Back in Unity editor, I see the component `Audio Clip Jump` inside GameObject.Avatar, and I drag and dropped the .wav file onto it.

Then I go into the game, and the jump animation plays, but I have no sound :(

here is a screenshot of the Unity editor:

[image]

and like I said, just the 2 lines in the C# file

Comment: Do you have an active [AudioListener](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AudioListener.html) in your scene?

Comment: It should work. Are you using 3D sound? If that's the case check max distance parameter under 3d audio settings and the location of the source relative to the audio listener. Also, have you got an audio listener somewhere?is it active?

Answer (score 2):

- Check that there is a [AudioListener](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-AudioListener.html) in the scene, probably attached to the **Camera**.
- Try using the second argument on the [PlayOneShot](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) function, to indicate the **volume**.
- Remember that having and **AudioListener** in the same **GameObject** containing the **AudioSource** doesn't work (for some reason).
- If all fails, try playing the sound from another **Component**, which should only have the code for playing the sound.

Comment: /* AudioListener in the same GameObject containing the AudioSource doesn't work */ thanks. Solved my problem.  However, in later versions, that is not a problem.